# pandasで固定値列を複数持つDataFrameを作成したい

Tags: python, pandas

変数（数値）、a,b,cがあった際に、複数の固定の列を追加して縦持ちのDataFrameを作成したいです。
やりたいことは以下のような事になります。

このような3つの値（DataFrameではありません）があった場合に

```
a
b
c
```

以下のように先頭？に列毎に固定の値を設定した列を追加したい。

```
hoge huga a
hoge huga b
hoge huga c
```

コードですと以下のような形になります。

```
import pandas as pd
# 実際にはa,b,cは集計値なので固定ではありません。
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'

# こういった形で、値が固定の列を複数先頭に追加して縦持ちでDataFrameを作成したい
df = pd.DataFrame([['hoge', 'huga', a],['hoge', 'huga', b],['hoge', 'huga', c]])
```

このままでも実現はできておりますが、固定値の設定が分散している事からもう少しスマートに実現できればと考えております。

Comment: カラムを追加するということでしょうか？ `df = pd.DataFrame([['hoge', 'huga'],['hoge', 'huga'],['hoge', 'huga']])` としておいて、`df[2] = ['a', 'b', 'c']` とするのはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'
df = pd.DataFrame({
    0: 'hoge',
    1: 'huga',
    2: [a,b,c]})
```

でどうでしょうか